# Unity NavMeshAgent won't move unless the player gets to a certain location

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I'm using NavmeshAgent to make the enemy chase the player. Below is my script

```
public Transform goal;
private NavMeshAgent agent;
private bool playerInSightRange;
private bool playerInAttackRange;
private void Awake()
{
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    ChasePlayer();
}

private void ChasePlayer()
{
    Debug.Log(agent.SetDestination(goal.position));
}
```

However, the enemy is not moving unless my player arrives at a certain location, beside the fridge to be specific. I'm really confused right now and any help would be appreciated. I have attached my navmesh map below. Thank you!

[image: Person holding the sword is the enemy]

Answer (score 0):

I somehow solved the issue by changing the destination y value to be the y value of the navmesh agent.